# How do I set a domain name to an OpenCPU app?

Tags: opencpu

I have a Ubuntu 18.4 LTS server running `OpenCPU`, and am able to run the application `myapp` by pointing my browser to the address `http://myip/ocpu/library/myapp/www/`. I wish to make the app available via the domain name `mydomain.name`, and have set up DNS records to point to `myip`.

On the server side, I created a file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/myapp.conf`, which looks like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.name
    DocumentRoot /ocpu/lib/myapp/www
    LogLevel info
    ErrorLog /var/log/myapp/apache_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/myapp/apache_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

However, `sudo systemctl reload apache2` throws an error since it cannot find the documentRoot `/ocpu/lib/myapp/www`. In fact, there is no directory `ocpu` on the server.

I suspect that I need to set up a `.conf` file in `/etc/opencpu/server.conf.d`, but the structure of those files look very different from `myapp.conf` as given above, and I do not see an entry for a `ServerName`.

How do I redirect `mydomain.name` to `http://myip/ocpu/library/myapp/www/`?

Comment: Changed DocumentRoot to `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/myapp/www`, added log files, reloaded and made `www-data` owner of `/usr/... /www` directory. Now getting "You don't have permission to access / on this server"

Comment: Another failed attempt: Copy the contents of `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/myapp/www` into `/var/www/myapp`. The page now loads, but the `openCPU` functionality disappears, probably because of cross-posting.

Answer (score 4):

If the site is available through `http://myip/ocpu/library/myapp/www/` but should be available through `http(s)://mydomain.name` you can simply create a proxy entry in your apache2 configuration like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.name

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass "/" "http://myip/ocpu/library/myapp/www/"
</VirtualHost>
```

**Note**: You may have to enable the proxy module(s): `sudo a2enmod proxy` & `sudo a2enmod proxy_http`

This will serve the website `http://myip/ocpu/library/myapp/www/` on `mydomain.name`.

Make sure to restart apache2 (`sudo service apache2 restart`) after editing the configuration and enabling the module(s).

Sources:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension

Comment: Changed it according to your recommendation. When I now enter `mydomain.name` in the browser, the server becomes fully unresponsive, and I need to reboot the server from the AWS control panel. Could there be an endless loop here?

Comment: If you have other configurations active, a loop can occur. Check your apache2 logs. There will be the same message multiple times, if it's a loop. Otherwise the site may be broken. Or the site tries to redirect you to `http://myip/ocpu/library/myapp/www/`, which is redirected to `mydomain.name` resulting in a endless loop. Can you configure the sites `webroot` in any configuration of the software?